# How to use xargs for deleting iptables rules?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, iptables, xargs

I have to remove some rules from iptables which is furnished for a port. I am trying to delete rules using line numbers. So there can be multiple rules for a port hence more than one line number can be there. How can i achieve this in a single command using xargs?

This is what i tried(port num 69):

iptables -L FORWARD --line-number | grep "dpt:69" |  cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs iptables -D FORWARD

This will work if there is only one rule. But will throw error "Bad argument" on multiple line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `xargs` will assume that the command can accept multiple input on one command. For example, `echo file1 file2 file3 | xargs rm` would only emit one `rm` command to delete 3 files, and that would be fine.

If the command has a limit then you need to tell `xargs` about it:

```
xargs -n1 iptables -D FORWARD
```

... which means "limit to 1 argument per command". If you use `-i` to insert the argument somewhere specific that that will work too.

BTW, if you're putting this in a script then you should also consider adding `--no-run-if-empty`, or else it'll still run the command even when the `grep` finds nothing.